# MS Access Shared Database Saving

Tags: database, ms-access-2010, shared-memory

I have a Microsoft Access File that is a shared file. Advanced settings set it to shared by everyone, Default open mode is Shared, No record locks, Open databases by using record-level locking. Enable DDE Refresh and default encryption.

Multiple users can open it at the same time, however if I save I get this message: Microsoft Access can't save design changes because another user has the file open…(etc.)

Any advice on where to begin?

UPDATED INFORMATION:
Apparently the database is already split, so I'm going to do some research in this area. Let me know if you have seen this before and can help though!

Comment: Access is basically not for sharing. You should consider migrating to a full DB server (MySQL, SQLServer, Postgres) for this type of functionality

Answer (score 0):

By definition, you cannot make design changes when another user is using the file.

Multiple users can access and edit records at the same time. The settings you set, control how strict the locking process is in order to avoid conflicts.

Design changes, not possible, no way!

Comment: We're not trying to make design changes, we're trying to edit and save records at the same time.

Comment: Well if you get the message `Microsoft Access can't save design changes because another user has the file open...` then apparently you are trying to make design changes even if you don't realise it. Check what you are doing to see where you could be doing something that constitutes a design change.